# global var in javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I'm newbie and have to following question:

i declared a global variable and alter the value within a function. But outside the value is still the old.

```
var allowDrag = 'false';

$.get('/cakeorga2/ajax/is_admin/', function (data) {
    allowDrag = data;
    console.log ('allowDrag in function : '+allowDrag);
});

console.log ('outside of the function : '+ allowDrag);
```

the console log was:

```
outside of the function : false
allowDrag in function : true
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Google what the **a** in ajax stands for.

Comment: this is asynchronous call, allowDrag is updated after the response is received but the outer body is executed before that, hence you're getting such response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.get` is a shorthand method of [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Perform an **asynchronous** HTTP (Ajax) request.

An ajax call is usually async so the main `console.log` will be fired before the $.get execution is completed (as you can see in the console order) and in that moment the `allowDrag` value is still `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You were trapped. Global variables behave exactly as you expected. The reason it does not have the new value in your second `console.log` is a different one: By the time you execute the `console.log`, the ajax call issued with `$.get` has not been answered yet. If you need to use it like that you must make the call synchronous by using the `async: false` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use deferred.then() to call the second console.log() only after the value has been updated (ajax GET has been successful)

```
$.get('/cakeorga2/ajax/is_admin/', function (data) {
  allowDrag = data;
  console.log ('allowDrag in function : '+allowDrag);
}).then( function(){
     console.log ('outside of the function : '+ allowDrag);
   }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your `ajax` call is [asynchronous](https://www.google.ro/search?q=asynchronous&oq=asyn&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2071j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8#q=asynchronous+call). Asynchronous (in your use case) means your `outside of the function console.log` will execute before your `ajax` call returns.

Answer (score 1):

Well that might very well be because the console.log outside the function gets called before the one inside the function since you have to call the function yourself and the code around it gets "played" automatically. But since I'm not familiar with Ajax/jQuery I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Do it synchronous with **$.ajax()**

```
var allowDrag = 'false';

allowDrag  = $.ajax(
              {
               url:'/cakeorga2/ajax/is_admin/',
               async:false
              }).responseText;

console.log ('outside of the function : '+ allowDrag);
```

Comment: Wow... so many useful Answers so i short time (15 minutes). Meanwhile a solved with Sunny suggestions! Thanks

Comment: @vagus1975 glad it helped! please mark it as answer so that others would grab it in one go... thanks.